# Why it doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

Before 1 min I started in developing a website.

At first I started in making the position of the header fixed then I made the wrapper div that called "all" but this div didn't appear please give me a solution.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Haettenschweiler;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background: #363333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
.menu{
 list-style-type:none; 
}
.menu li{
 float:right;
 font-size:24px;
 display:block;
 min-width:125px; 
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:5px;
}
.menu li a{
 min-width:125px;
 display:block;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none; 
}

#all {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Gloucester MT;
}
#left{
 float:left;
 background:yellow;
 width:13%;
}
#right{
 float:right;
 background:yellow;
 width:13%;
}
#center{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
 <div class="header">
  <div id="logo">1111</div>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="1.php">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.php">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.php">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.php">4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="all">
 <div id="left">sadf</div>
 <div id="right">sasadf</div>
 <div id="center">sadf</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your `.all` div with `position: relative;` and set a `top` value equals to the `height` of the header.

This is because if you do not set `position: relative;` it is being displayed taking as reference the parent(the webpage) so it is the reason why your `.all` div is displayed in the top-left corner of your webpage.

The `header` is displayed above of your `.all` div because it is fixed, and fixed elements goes out of the normal flow.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Haettenschweiler;
}

#header {
  height: 60px;
  background: #363333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
.menu{
 list-style-type:none; 
}
.menu li{
 float:right;
 font-size:24px;
 display:block;
 min-width:125px; 
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:5px;
}
.menu li a{
 min-width:125px;
 display:block;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none; 
}

#all {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Gloucester MT;
}
#left{
 float:left;
 background:yellow;
 width:13%;
}
#right{
 float:right;
 background:yellow;
 width:13%;
}
#center{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
 <div class="header">
  <div id="logo">1111</div>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="1.php">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.php">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.php">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.php">4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="all">
 <div id="left">sadf</div>
 <div id="right">sasadf</div>
 <div id="center">sadf</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#all` div is sitting behind the `#header` div.

It's concealed by the height of this div because when you set an element's position to `absolute` or `fixed` you're taking it out of the flow of the document.

Declaring a `padding-top` rule, equal to, or great than the height of `#header` will push `#all` down far enough into view.

**Example:**

```
#all {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

**In-browser Developing & Troubleshooting Tip** 
If you inspect these elements through your browser's developer tool you can see how they stack in relation to each other. For example, chrome will highlight the element on your screen when you hover over the mark-up of said element in the developer tool console/IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Because your #header div has position:fixed it will not affect the positioning of other elements (i.e #all div). So the divs get rendered on top of each others. Try removing position:fixed from header if there's no need for it. Otherwise you have to manually move the #all div downwards a bit.